# Do third-party CA code signing certificates work on OS X?

Tags: macos, certificate

I have read Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

I have also read this thread:

[Non-Apple Issued Code Signing Certificate: Can it Work with Mac OS 10.8 Gatekeeper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833481/non-apple-issued-code-signing-certificate-can-it-work-with-mac-os-10-8-gatekeep)

Both clearly state that third-party CA code signing certificates won't work with Apple OS X.

However, various CAs offer Apple code signing certificates for sale. Couple examples here:

https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/apple-certificates.htm

https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/apple/index.html

There are other companies too. Which creates an impression that it is indeed possible to use a variety of certificaes with OS X.

These cannot be both right. Is there any explanation to the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did buy a digicert certificate for code signing. Their website says it can be used for codesigning OSX applications. Technically speaking this is true: you can sign your app with it. But it is not acceptable for GateKeeper. To have GateKeeper accept it it must be signed with an Apple certificate.

I contacted digicert about this and they agree with me. I told them to update their information on their website. Apparently they did not do so (yet?)